# Regex for No more than 2 consecutive numbers No more than 2 repeated characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to create a regex with conditions:

- Minimum length 6
- At least one number and one letter must be used
- No more than 2 consecutive numbers (like 123)
- No more than 2 repeated characters

What I am able to achieve

```
/^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,/?"])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,/?"]+$/
```

This validates that the string has at least one number and one letter.
Instead of consecutive numbers 123, it checks 111. and i am not able to add 4th condition in this.

Any further help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `What I am able to achieve` - and, what does that achieve ... as far as I can see, all that is achieved is `At least one number and one letter must be used` (and maybe `No more than 2 repeated characters` if you mean adjacent to each other) - to be honest, RegExp alone is probably not going to help with this - does it have to be a RegExp answer?

Comment: A negative lookahead might prove useful here, but password regex is a problem which is already well covered on Stack Overflow.  Have you done your own research?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Suggest if anything else needs to be added.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did look to the already answered questions and I came up with what I have added in the question.

Comment: add some valid and invalid input values

Answer (score 4):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?=[\D]*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=.{6,})(?!.*(\d)\1{2})(?!.*([a-zA-Z])(?:.*?\2){2,}).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RlYP2C/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?=[\D]*\d)` - positive lookahead - checks for the presence of a digit
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])` - positive lookahead - checks for the presence of a letter
- `(?=.{6,})` - positive lookahead - checks for the presence of atleast 6 literals
- `(?!.*(\d)\1{2})` - Negative lookahead - Checks for the ABSENCE of 3 consecutive digits. It will allow 2 consecutive digits though. If you do not want even 2 consecutive digits, then remove {2} from this part
- `(?!.*([a-zA-Z])(?:.*?\2){2,})` - Negative lookahead - validates that no letter should be present more than 2 times in the string
- `.*` - capture the string
- `$` - end of the string

**OUTPUT:**

```
jj112233         -Matches as it has atleast one letter, digit. Not more than 2 consecutive digits/letter. Has atleast 6 characters
jkhsfsndbf8uwwe  -matches 
a1234            -does not match as length<6 
nsds312          -matches
111aaa222        -does not match as it has more than 2 consecutive digits and also more than 2 repeated letters 
aa11bbsd         -match
hgshsadh12       -does not match as it has more than 2 `h`
hh8uqweuu        -does not match as it has more than 2 `u`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this fails to catch "No more than 2 repeated characters". Eg. "aa1aa1aa" 'a' should not be repeated more than 2 times but here it is done 6 times.

Comment: @AmanGupta I have updated the answer. I have added the 4th condition as well now. No letter will be repeated more than 2 times in the string.

Comment: It matched "No more than 2 repeated characters" correctly. Although I needed to also add condition where consecutive numbers like 123, 456 are  not allowed.

Comment: and to match that I did this:  /(?!.*012)(?!.*123)(?!.*234)(?!.*345)(?!.*456)(?!.*567)(?!.*678)(?!.*789)(?!.*987)(?!.*876)(?!.*765)(?!.*654)(?!.*543)(?!.*432)(?!.*321)(?!.*210)(?!.*(.)\1{2,})(?!(^\D+$))(?!(^\d+$))(^.{6,}$)/

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.