# ASP.NET MVC 5: Create regular expression for model that cannot have 5 consecutive repeating characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a regular expression attribute for my MVC model. The regular expression needs to validate that the string...

- Does not have more than 5 consecutive repeating characters
- At least 6 characters long

Here is what I was able to come up with given [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030785/regex-for-no-more-than-2-consecutive-numbers-no-more-than-2-repeated-characters):

```
[RegularExpression('^(?=[\D]*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=.{6,})(?!.*(\d)\1{4})(?!.*([a-zA-Z])(?:.*?\4){4,}).*$')]
```

When I tried to use this regex in my model, I was getting "Unrecognized escape sequence" errors for each backslash. How do I need to modify this regex so that it works with C#?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging I found my answer. I also added a max string length of 20:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*(.)\1{5})[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$")]
```